# Continuous deployment of a single-page app?

Tags: node.js, single-page-application, continuous-deployment

Here's the only solutions I've come up with (don't know if they're the adequate though):

Server-side updates:

> Version every client request and have the proxy route to the
>   appropriate server version.

Cient-side updates:

> Notify the client over a websocket connection to re-inject the
>   script/style tags after X number of idle minutes thereby invoking 2
>   ajax requests for updated JS/CSS files and refresh the HTML of the
>   page.

I don't know if this is something that shouldn't be a priority in the early stages of the app and I should just take the entire app down for "scheduled maintenance" in the early hours of the morning.

For SEO purposes, the front page's HTML is sent by the server along with the single JS/CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Right Thing (tm) is to make build your single page application in a way where it consumes RESTful API which is public quality.  In other words, think about it as if you are publishing your API to the world and when making changes make them backwards compatible.  I think this is not as hard as it might think and will leave you with a cleaner system.  Certainly better than building a complex versioning and live patching scheme!

Comment: So API breaking changes would have to be a slow transition. What would be the appropriate way to introduce new features or remove old ones if "upgrading" the API was not the change in question. Upgrades to APIs can be coded for backwards compatibility but feature additions or subtractions involve direct changes in the client and server side code.

Comment: Well feature addition is not a problem: old cached clients will not know about it and won't use it?

Comment: But that's a problem if the old clients _never_ refresh the page. How would I ever push or pull features from these clients?

Comment: do you really envision this as a problem?  Do you have some kind of weird client kiosk setup which makes this an actual problem, or are you just inventing problems to make your life interesting?

Comment: It's my job to "envision" the worst so that I'm prepared for said scenario and don't get stuck in a situation where there's nothing I can do. How could I possibly assume that users will refresh the page when the site already updates _everything_ in real-time. There is a giant slice of users which keep their machines on with tabs to frequently visited sites open. Having said that, I think I've come up with how to solve this in a pragmatic way.

Comment: "I think I've come up with how to solve this in a pragmatic way" - would you like to add that as an answer here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying to a tomcat server, you can simply overwrite the .js and .css files in the correct "deployed" location....

copy files to /your/deployed/app/location/webapp/js, etc this is a quick and easy way to "hot deploy" a new JS / CSS w/o taking the server down..... however if you have backend support that also needs to be updated, that may require a restart of the tomcat service. in which case something like Jenkins might help. http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2012/03/21/integrating-jenkins-and-apache-tomcat-continuous-deployment

Comment: I doubt he is deploying node.js to tomcat.

Comment: I do all the time. Using Java and Spring as the backend. Node does not HAVE to act as the server.

Comment: I don't understand then.  Are you using node.js on the client side (in the browser)?  Which pieces?

Comment: I switched away from node 3 months ago, however up until then I was using it to simply package / handle dependencies.  Once this was accomplished I deployed via a Tomcat instance with a Java / Spring backend API.  The Node app was simply included on a webpage as part of the content.. It does not have to act as a backend server.